# How to bind C-[ for real?

Tags: key-bindings

<kbd>C-[</kbd> is equivalent to the escape key on US English keyboards, thus, any attempt at binding it will mess up <kbd>M-</kbd> behaviour.

Emacs seems to have no trouble telling <kbd><escape></kbd> and <kbd>C-[</kbd> apart in GUI frames. The following works fine and bindings starting with <kbd>M-</kbd> remain to be working:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>") (lambda () (interactive) (message "<escape>")))
```

However, if I bind

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-[") (lambda () (interactive) (message "C-[")))
```

suddenly emacs goes crazy and binding like <kbd>M-x</kbd> break. Moreover, pressing <kbd>C-[</kbd> refuses to trigger the bound lambda. Interestingly enough, <kbd>C-x @ c [</kbd> (apply modifier control to open bracket) still says `C-[ is undefined`.

Is there any way of binding something to <kbd>C-[</kbd> without breaking emacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution is a bit kludky, but seems to work:

Let `~/.xbindkeysrc` contain the following:

```
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Control_L]\[F13]'"
  m:0x14 + c:34

"xvkbd -xsendevent -text '\[Control_L]\[F14]'"
  m:0x14 + c:35
```

Now `xbindkeys` will translate <kbd>C-[</kbd> to <kbd>C-<f13></kbd> and <kbd>C-]</kbd> to <kbd>C-<f14></kbd>, so they can be bound in emacs freely. You will probably want to bind `abort-recursive-edit` to something other than <kbd>C-]</kbd>, for example, <kbd>C-S-g</kbd>.

The downside is that now <kbd>C-[</kbd> is broken in every application except Emacs, which could be fixed by adding some logic to test whether the key combination is being sent to emacs...

Comment: FWIW, I don't think there's anything special about `C-]`.

Comment: Yeah, me neither, but for some odd reason my `C-]` binding stopped working after I fired up Xbindkeys, so I rebound that one, too.

Comment: When I install xbindkeys and use your code above, hitting "C-[" and "C-]" doesn't do anything. it detects my Ctrl click but is still waiting for input after I hit Ctrl. running Ubuntu 20.10 and Xfce desktop

Answer (score 14):

You cannot really change the <kbd>C-[</kbd> binding at user-level 
maps, as
you would do with `global-set-key`. However, you can change it as 
a keyboard event before it reaches those keymaps. You can say for example:

```lisp
(define-key input-decode-map 
    (kbd "C-[") 
    [control-bracketleft])
```

and then use `[control-bracketleft]` in your keymaps. Pretty simple isn't it?

### Director's Cut

Unfortunately, it is not that simple, and this solution requires 
some adjustments, which will appear to be very painful. You've been warned.
But let's see first why user-level maps cannot answer the question.
In the following, I refer to the Emacs Lisp manual for emacs 26.1 when I 
say "see something"
without more precision.

<kbd>C-[</kbd> is interpreted at a
very early stage as the ASCII control character `ESC` (see 
21.7.1 - *Keyboard Events*).
This code is spread out all other the place as the prefix
for longer sequences. There is a reason for that: `ESC` is 
actually the meta prefix (see `meta-prefix-char`), and all 
bindings that read 
<kbd>M-</kbd>*something* will translate to a sequence that starts with `ESC`. 
Thus, changing the global map won't be enough: you need first to change `meta-prefix-char`, then
to remap `ESC` to your new `meta-prefix-char` in each and every map that uses <kbd>M-</kbd> before you can safely map <kbd>C-[</kbd>.

OK then, of course: let's use `input-decode-map`. There is 
a couple of similar maps we may get tempted to use (see sections 21.8.3 
and 22.14), but let's stick to this one.
And
well... this works! You're done, aren't you?

Actually, no, the story does not end here. This works... as long as you're 
using a window system. If due to bad luck you're jailed
in the linux console in an emergency state, you realize how
dramatic the situation has become: arrow keys, <kbd>Home</kbd>, and
of course <kbd>M-</kbd> bindings, are all garbage. Why? Because when the terminal says `ESC` (which it does when you type <kbd>C-[</kbd>), it really *means* `ESC`, and starts
a sequence of the same kind it uses to transmit non-ASCII characters.

Observing the disaster, you may consider it wise to protect 
the above `input-decode-map` modification in such a way
that it activates only in the case a window system is controlling 
the keyboard:

```lisp
(let ((frame (framep (selected-frame))))
  (or (eq  t  frame)
      (eq 'pc frame)

      (define-key input-decode-map 
                  (kbd "C-[") 
                  [control-bracketleft])
     )))
```

Terminals then work as they used to.

Now, can we deal with <kbd>C-[</kbd> on terminals?
Actually, yes we can, on the linux console as well as on the other terminal 
emulators I can play with. But that makes the story a 
pretty long one, as new characters enter the scene. For it is no more
emacs alone: the terminal has now the central role.

Let's lend an ear on what the linux console has to say. Type <kbd>C-v</kbd> before
some key to hear it plain. <kbd>C-[</kbd> is `ESC`; so is <kbd>Esc</kbd>. 
The up arrow sounds like `ESC [ A`, while <kbd>M-a</kbd> is
`ESC A`. Hmm... Looks like this meta key circumvolutions in 
emacs isn't it? 
Anyway.

Unless we're ready to play some tricks based on the time
elapsed between the character events (which by the way won't distinguish 
<kbd>Esc</kbd> from <kbd>C-[</kbd>), it seems we've got no choice but to tell the 
console what we actually don't mean `ESC` when we type <kbd>C-[</kbd>. Moreover, it appears pretty soon
that <kbd>C-[</kbd> is not the only
problem with stock terminal codes: modifiers are most of time
erased out the transmitted information. We need to customize the
terminal for the very same reason we customize emacs: it would be
so much more practical if we do.

At this point, you shall dare a deep look into your terminal's documentation eyes:
man pages `loadkeys(1)` for the 
linux console, for xterm
`xterm(1)` in section *Custom Key Bindings*, and *whatever-i-dont-know* for other terminals. 
In `KDE konsole`, you can
define custom translations in *Settings/Edit Current Profile...* 
then *Keyboard*. Here is an excerpt from `~/.local/share/konsole/Test.keytab`
after playing with this latter dialog:

```
key [+Ctrl+AnyModifier : "\EO*["
```

Once you have the terminal send `ESC O 5 [` for
<kbd>C-[</kbd> (as in the above configuration), you can go back to emacs. 
For of course, 
you're not done yet.

To instruct emacs what dialect a given terminal uses, you can
adjust `input-decode-map`. Yes, this is fortuitously the very one we've modified
at the beginning of this story, and this is the very one
`term/xterm.el` touches when xterm is involved. A good place for the adjustment
is `tty-setup-hook` (see section 40.1.3):

```lisp
(add-hook 'tty-setup-hook 
   (lambda ()
    (let ((term (getenv "TERM")))
      (cond 
        (;; xterm-function-map not in doc, but in term/xterm.el
         (boundp 'xterm-function-map) 
         (map-my-term-codes xterm-function-map))

        ((equal term "linux")
         (map-my-term-codes input-decode-map))
        )
      )))
```

Be aware this hook only runs if you're in a terminal. Thus,
you cannot insert here the code for the window system initialization.
Here's the translation function by itself:

```lisp
(defun map-my-term-codes (map)
      (define-key map (kbd "M-O 5 [") 
                      [control-bracketleft])
      )
```

And then you can take some rest: it's the end of the journey. Of course, if you don't care about
terminals, it's quick as you'll skip all the painful part. But you'll admit 
it's also rather incomplete.

Two final notes:

- I choose `ESC O 5 [` to code <kbd>C-[</kbd>. This is just
  an example: I won't pretend it's a *good* choice. Only the `5`
  part, which means <kbd>C-</kbd>, seems to obey some kind of established
  convention
- configuring the linux console leaves a bad taste: it does
  not seem possible to do the binding without using an 
  intermediate *existing* symbol, and those I would need
  *do not exist*. I use symbols in
  the <kbd>F21</kbd>-<kbd>F246</kbd> range as in most internet examples, but
  it is not very satisfying. It's OK for a few unrelated bindings,
  but it won't serve a systematic schema.

## Edit

- I've completed this with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> case - which has its own personality - in another post: [How to remove bindings to the ESC prefix key](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14755/how-to-remove-bindings-to-the-esc-prefix-key#52338)
- here is a fragment of a configuration to feed `loadkeys` with. I put this in /root/custom.kmap, and load it when I need to (which is rare). My actual config also maps arrows and different combinations of modifier, but it's rather long, choice of symbols and sequences is questionable, and I'm not sure the keycodes for my keyboard will match yours. So let's keep it at its due level: this is nothing but an illustration.

  ```
  keymaps 0-127

  # http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-15.html
  # web+man:keymaps
  # web+man:loadkeys

  # escape
  keycode  1  = F100
      alt keycode  1 = Escape # keep the Escape behavior somewhere          

  # keycode  26 = bracketleft
      control keycode 26 = F115 # Control_bracketleft does not exist          

  string F100     = "\033OO" # map this to [escape] in map-my-term-codes
  string F115     = "\033O5["
  ```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer. But surely even a great answer like this surely doesn't need to be bumped to the top of the front page 34 times. Each bump has a small cost which is shared by the community: checking for spam, looking if there's new interesting content, etc. Maybe you could group minor improvements together? Or just stick with what you have. Speaking from experience, there's no such thing as the perfect post, at some point you just have to move on.

Comment: @Gilles Got it, and sorry for that. I was not aware there was some issue adjusting this at wish.