# How to bind C-[ for real (seriously for real this time)

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

Is there any way to bind `C-[` to something and not have all `M-` (Meta) bindings messed up?

Not [the first time](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7832/how-to-bind-c-for-real) this question comes up. Unfortunately, the only solution offered in the previous thread is **a)** Linux specific, **b)** requires an external tool (again Linux specific) that has nothing to do with Emacs. In the same vein I could have used something like **Karabiner** on a OS X to steal the `C-[` sequence before Emacs ever gets it but this is clunky and expensive.

Given that it is Emacs that insists on translating `C-[` to `ESC`, `C-i` to `TAB` and probably others I would very much like to break these relationships and get precious key sequences back. Recently I ran full speed into this problem and [blamed](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/issues/447) quiet innocent **smartparens** mode.

A possible solution that involved `function-key-map` and `key-translation-map` was [discussed here](https://superuser.com/questions/173851/linux-remap-ctrl-key) but alas it either no longer works or did not work in the first place (or I'm doing something wrong). I think it was going in the right direction though.

Comment: Emacs does not insist "on translating `C-[` to `ESC`". The two are [**the same thing**](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html). Likewise, `C-i` and `TAB` are different names for the **same** ASCII control code.

Comment: @Drew It is not the least bit obvious that key combinations with control _must_ map to ASCII control codes (of which there are only 32) in a GUI application. (Or, heck, even in xterm, which has a modifyOtherKeys mode to send unique escape sequences in many cases, though I'm not sure about these in particular)

Comment: @Random832: You are right to distinguish *keys* from *characters*. It is somewhat logical and straightforward for an editor to map the **key sequence** `C-[` (press `Ctrl` and hit `[`) to the `C-[` control **character** (aka the `ESC` character), but no, that is not obligatory for someone designing an editor. And yes, Emacs does that. `C-[` and `ESC` are the same character, but the keys `Ctrl` + `[` and `Esc` need not be mapped to any particular characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adapted from [my own config](https://github.com/wasamasa/dotemacs/blob/8503aa99856d2f0142ee205b15f9177eb4886f6e/init.org#c-i):

```
(define-key input-decode-map [?\C-\[] (kbd "<C-[>"))
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-[>") 'butterfly)
```

This will obviously only work in the GUI.

edit: Note that `input-decode-map` is terminal-local which means modifying it won't work if you're using `emacsclient`, but will do if you're using `emacs`. I've fixed the issue in my config by wrapping it in a command operating on a frame and adding it to the `after-make-frame-functions` hook.

Comment: thank you this appears legit! I wonder if there's a way to prevent Emacs from treating Meta and ESC as the same thing? Also am wondering if I'm simply messing up some Emacs terminology and not thinking straight here

Comment: That's a different question, please open a new one for that.

Comment: interestingly having `<C-i>` and `<C-[>` bound back to `TAB` and `ESC` in the global-map like you suggest in your config flat out crashes my Emacs every time I hit em:

Comment: Well, considering that you happen to be the guy who has handed in [a bug for helm crashing upon input of the letter "j"](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/779), I blame your Emacs build for being crashy and would suggest you to try a different one for OS X.

Comment: believe me I did try many a build. Will be another mystery I'll have to live with. I'll manage -) thank you for the solution

Comment: btw, @wasamasa thank u for linking to your config. It is very educational