# How to disable the close frame shortcut?

Tags: key-bindings, frames

Apparently pressing `C-[` (three times in a row it seems?) (or alternatively ESC three times) closes a frame. I oftentimes accidentally press `C-[` when I meant to press `C-p`. I tried to disable it with

`(define-key "\C-[" KEY nil)` which does nothing

as well as

```
(dolist (key '("\C-["))
 (global-unset-key key))
```

which for some reason makes my meta key not work anymore.

How can I disable `\C-[`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C-[` is bound to `ESC` with this knowledge:

Your question has already been answered [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10271/how-to-bind-c-for-real-seriously-for-real-this-time/10273#10273) and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17688/how-to-unbind-c-shortcut)

For how to remap `ESC` have a look [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14759/15749).
For remapping `ESC` see last link the correct order is:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "C-<escape>") (kbd "ESC"))
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "ESC") (kbd "C-g"))
```

Comment: Instead of repeating an answer to a duplicate question, please vote to close the question as a duplicate.